# Join an array by a comma and a space

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, tostring

I have an array that I want converted to a comma delimited string. `Array.toString()` works, but if I have a rather large array it won't wrap because there are no spaces after the commas:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = ['css','html','xhtml','html5','css3','javascript','jquery','lesscss','arrays','wordpress','facebook','fbml','table','.htaccess','php','c','.net','c#','java'].toString();
// css,html,xhtml,html5,css3,javascript,jquery,lesscss,arrays,wordpress,facebook,fbml,table,.htaccess,php,c,.net,c#,java
```

How can I have spaces after the commas in order to allow line/word wrapping?

Example output:

```
css, html, xhtml, html5, css3, javascript, jquery, lesscss, arrays, wordpress, facebook, fbml, table, .htaccess, php, c, .net, c#, java
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289403/jquery-convert-javascript-array-to-string/12810028#12810028

Answer (score 207, accepted):

In JavaScript there's a [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method on arrays to get a string, which you can provide the delimiter to.  In your case it'd look like this:

```
var myArray = ['css','html','xhtml','html5','css3','javascript','jquery','lesscss','arrays','wordpress','facebook','fbml','table','.htaccess','php','c','.net','c#','java'];
var myString = myArray.join(', ');
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/XhEQ3/)

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this without the `.join()` method?

Answer (score 27):

Use `array.join(", ");` and it should work

Answer (score 2):

```
 string.Join(", ", new string[] { "css", "html", "xhtml", ..etc });
```

This prints the items with a comma and a space

[edit] I'm sorry, did not see it was for javascript. My code is c# :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way by the regex

```js
let arr = ['css', 'html', 'xhtml', 'html5', 'css3', 'javascript', 'jquery', 'lesscss', 'arrays', 'wordpress', 'facebook', 'fbml', 'table', '.htaccess', 'php', 'c', '.net', 'c#', 'java'].toString();

let myString = arr.replace(/,[s]*/g, ", ");


console.log(myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw in a comment the question of how to make that without the `.join()` function.

Here is one tricky way:

```js
const array_of_strings = ['css','html','xhtml','html5','css3','javascript','jquery','lesscss','arrays','wordpress','facebook','fbml','table','.htaccess','php','c','.net','c#','java']
const separator = ', '
const result = array_of_strings.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + separator + currentValue);
console.log(result)
```