# Jquery JSON array from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, string

I have such array in Jquery code:

```
var marr = new Array();

marr[0] = new Object();
marr[0]["name"] = "Spot 1";
marr[0]["value"] = 20;

marr[1] = new Object();
marr[1]["name"] = "Spot 2";
marr[1]["value"] = 70;
```

How can I represent this array as a (more or less) user friendly string (to give users an ability to send some values as plugin options). An than parse it back for jquery?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289403/jquery-convert-javascript-array-to-string

Comment: or simply dont use an array, use an JSON object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have generated a JSON string from the `marr` array. It may had given you what you are looking for.

```
> console.log(JSON.stringify(marr));
[
    {
        "name": "Spot 1",
        "value": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "Spot 2",
        "value": 70
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
var marr = [ {"name": "Spot 1", "value":20}, {"name": "Spot 2", "value":70} ];
```

This is same as the code you mentioned above.

Comment: But then i use something like var name = marr[i].name to get array values, so i need "titles" for array items...

Comment: Updated my answer.. Now `marr[1].name` will give you `Spot 1`

Answer (score 1):

this will be json representation of array

```
var marr=[
         {"name":"spot 1","value":20}
         {"name":"spot 2","value":70}
         ]
```