# jquery.text() vs document.write()

Tags: jquery

I expect `#text` to print something on the screen; as, when I use alert(numbers), it works..

http://jsfiddle.net/hYarj/

```
function int_arr(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
var numbers = [20, 7, 65, 10, 3, 0, 8, -60];
numbers.sort(int_arr);
$('#text').text(numbers);
```

Comment: Convert the array into a string: `numbers.toString()`.

Comment: convert numbers to string using numbers.toString() or numbers.join(',') and also confirm that $("#text") is not an input element like textbox or textarea if you are using input element then use method $("#text").val(numbers.join(","));

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#text').text(numbers.toString());
```

or

```
$('#text').text(numbers.join(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

number is array that create problem...convert into string first

```
function int_arr(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
var numbers = [20, 7, 65, 10, 3, 0, 8, -60];
numbers.sort(int_arr);
$('#text').text(numbers.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery `.text()` is only used for string.

**Jquery .text() :**

Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements.

[See Here](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

And you use `Array` with `.text()`, it's not correct method.

For this, first you need to convert array into string.

example -

```
array.toString();

array.join(",");
```

[Convery Array into string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289403/jquery-convert-javascript-array-to-string)

**document.write()**

The write() method writes HTML expressions or JavaScript code to a document.

[See more](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp)